# Whats the difference between gravity feed solenoid valve and normal solenoid valves?

Tags: solenoid-valve

I am new to solenoid valves; I know the basic principal, it's just like normal valve but solenoid can be controlled using DC/AC current.

But my question is:

What's the difference between **gravity feed solenoid valve** and **normal solenoid valves**?
What are the applications of gravity feed solenoid valves as I have seen many normal solenoid valves used in washing machines and water purifiers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normal solenoid valves require some amount of pressure like 3psi for the valve to open. Gravity feed solenoid can allow liquid to flow through at any pressure.